# Virtualbox settings with Windows 10 guest and Linux host

Tags: virtualbox

I've got a Linux OS as host and Windows 10 as Virtualbox guest.
I have some questions regarding the Virtualbox settings for this configuration:

- About the 3D Acceleration, the Virtualbox manual doesn't say anything about Windows 10 guest. So does anyone know if it works?
  And more generally, is there a performance advantage to enable it for a basic use of Windows (no video games, no specific 3D software)?
- About the number of processors to enable for the guest, I can enable 1 to 4, what is the best setting regarding performance?
- Are there other settings to change to make the Windows guest more efficient (paravirtualization, chipset, EFI, PAE/NX, 2D video acceleration)?

Comment: Yes; It will work; How many processors you want to make visible to the guest os is entirely up to you (question seeking opinions are not on topic here at Superset), what does your research indicate?

Comment: @Ramhound, Regarding performance, does it make any difference if I set 1 or 4 processors?

Comment: Same difference it makes to the host os.